# FancyBox iframe to open after third page visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, popup, fancybox

I currently have a JavaScript function that increments a cookie value after each page visit. On the third visit I would like an iframe FancyBox to open. Below is a snippet of where I am stuck:

```
<script>
visits = getCookie('nVisits');
if (!visits){visits = 1};
if (visits == 3 ){++visits;

/* WHAT DO I PUT HERE :( */

}
if (visits != 3){++visits;
cookieData = visits;
setCookie('nVisits',cookieData,expDate) 
}
</script>
```

I assume this needs to call a hidden anchor tag or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if (visits == 3 ){++visits;
    /* WHAT DO I PUT HERE :( */
    jQuery.fancybox({
        href: "another-site.html",
        type: "iframe" // for external pages
    });
}
```

Now, you can set another `type` of content like `image`, `ajax` or `html` for instance so you would need to set both, `href` and `type` API options/values accordingly.

Comment: This worked a treat! Thanks, All I need to do now is customise the look and feel of the Fancybox. I assume is is all done underneath 'type'?

Comment: Also the URL I enter opens with my base URL before it so I keep getting my page not found page!

Comment: @user3045375  whatever you want to open depends on what you set in the `href`, in case of external pages, they may have their own css styles. To avoid "not found" errors, make sure that the path is correct and works outside of fancybox in a new tab or window